# Cauchy Riemann equations, do these satisfy it??

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

[image]

I have this question and am unsure of my approach.

I have applied the Cauchy Riemann conditions to it:

[image]

and found that this condition is true. Is that sufficient and does it make sense?

Comment: Its clear you have one part of the C-R set of equations, I suggest doing the book work and see if both equations hold. The other equation is $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial v} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial u}$$ in your notation.

Answer (score 1):

$u,v$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations if and only if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic.

But if $f$ is holomorphic, then so is 
\begin{align}
g=\exp(if^2)&=\exp\big(i(u+iv)^2\big)=\exp\big(i(u^2-v^2)-2uv\big)\\
&=\exp(-2uv)\big(\cos(u^2-v^2)+i\sin(u^2-v^2)\big),
\end{align}
which implies that
$$
\exp(-2uv)\cos(u^2-v^2)\quad\text{and}\quad
\exp(-2uv)\sin(u^2-v^2),
$$
satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations.